# In AWS EKS, how can I define ingress to use one ALB for multiple subdomain URLs, each with their own certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have multiple services that need to be exposed to the internet, but I'd like to use a single ALB for them.

I am using the latest [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller), and I've been reading the documentation here (https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/guide/ingress/annotations/#traffic-routing), but I haven't found a clear explanation on how to achieve this.

Here's the setup:

I have service-a.example.com *-and-* service-b.example.com. They each have their own certificates within Amazon Certificate Manager.

Within Kubernetes, each has its own service object defined as follows (each unique):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: svc-a-service
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: traffic-port
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthy-threshold-count: '5'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/unhealthy-threshold-count: '2'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /index.html
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '30'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-timeout-seconds: '5'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '200'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=Test,App=ServiceA
spec:
  selector:
    app: service-a
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort
```

And each service has it's own Ingress object defined as follows (again, unique to each and with the correct certificates specified for each service):

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: svc-a-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: services
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-01234567898765432
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ip-address-type: ipv4
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.response-503: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"503","messageBody":"Unknown Host"}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: routing.http2.enabled=true,idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=600
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=Test
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:555555555555:certificate/33333333-2222-4444-AAAA-EEEEEEEEEEEE
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: svc-a-service
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: response-503
              servicePort: use-annotation
```

The HTTP to HTTPS redirection works as expected.

However -- there is no differentiation between my two apps for the load balancer to be able to know that traffic destined for service-a.example.com and service-b.example.com should be routed to two different target groups.

In the HTTP:443 listener rules in the console, it shows:

1. IF Path is /* THEN Forward to ServiceATargetGroup
2. IF Path is /* THEN Return fixed 503
3. IF Path is /* THEN Forward to ServiceBTargetGroup
4. IF Path is /* THEN Return fixed 503
5. IF Request otherwise not routed THEN Return fixed 404

So the important question here is:
**How should the ingress be defined to force traffic destined for service-a.example.com to ServiceATargetGroup - and traffic destined for service-b.example.com to ServiceBTargetGroup?**

And secondarily, I need the "otherwise not routed" to return a 503 instead of 404. I was expecting this to appear only once in the rules (be merged) - yet it is created for each ingress. How should my yaml be structured to achieve this?

Comment: if I'm correct, you asking how do you define only one ingress object, if that is so, you can use this probably: https://github.com/jakubkulhan/ingress-merge this will merge all the ingress you create using merge annotation, and create a single ingress object, which will then be applied or be used by the ALB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I eventually figured this out -- so for anyone else stumbling onto this post, here's how I resolved it:

The trick was not relying on merging between the Ingress objects. Yes, it can handle a certain degree of merging, but there's not really a one-to-one relationship between Services as TargetGroups and Ingress as ALB. So you have to be very cautious and aware of what's in each Ingress object.

Once I combined all of my ingress into a single object definition, I was able to get it working exactly as I wanted with the following YAML:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: svc-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: services
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/security-groups: sg-01234567898765432
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ip-address-type: ipv4
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.response-503: >
      {"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"503","messageBody":"Unknown Host"}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.svc-a-host: >
      {"type":"forward","forwardConfig":{"targetGroups":[{"serviceName":"svc-a-service","servicePort":80,"weight":100}]}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.svc-a-host: >
      [{"field":"host-header","hostHeaderConfig":{"values":["svc-a.example.com"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.svc-b-host: >
      {"type":"forward","forwardConfig":{"targetGroups":[{"serviceName":"svc-b-service","servicePort":80,"weight":100}]}}
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.svc-b-host: >
      [{"field":"host-header","hostHeaderConfig":{"values":["svc-b.example.com"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: routing.http2.enabled=true,idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=600
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=Test
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:555555555555:certificate/33333333-2222-4444-AAAA-EEEEEEEEEEEE,arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:555555555555:certificate/44444444-3333-5555-BBBB-FFFFFFFFFFFF
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: response-503
    servicePort: use-annotation
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - backend:
              serviceName: svc-a-host
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - backend:
              serviceName: svc-b-host
              servicePort: use-annotation
```

**Default Action:**

Set by specifying the serviceName and servicePort directly under `spec`:

```yaml
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: response-503
    servicePort: use-annotation
```

**Routing:**

Because I'm using subdomains and paths won't work for me, I simply omitted the path and instead relied on hostname as a condition.

```yaml
metadata:
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.svc-a-host: >
      {"type":"forward","forwardConfig":{"targetGroups":[{"serviceName":"svc-a-service","servicePort":80,"weight":100}]}}
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.svc-a-host: >
      [{"field":"host-header","hostHeaderConfig":{"values":["svc-a.example.com"]}}]
```

**End Result:**

The ALB rules were configured precisely how I wanted them:

- default action is a 503 fixed response
- all http traffic is redirected to https
- traffic is directed to TargetGroups based on the host header

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with one modification I would like to remind. If you dont specify port as a string within actions.${hostname} from now on you will get the following error: "msg"="Reconciler error"  --- cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field TargetGroupTuple.ForwardConfig.TargetGroups.ServicePort of type string

Answer (score 4):

AWS EKS now has a notion of `IngressGroups` so multiple ingresses can share one ingress controller. See [Application load balancing on Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html)

```
To share an application load balancer across multiple ingress resources using IngressGroups

To join an Ingress to an Ingress group, add the following annotation to a Kubernetes Ingress resource specification.

alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: <my-group>
The group name must be:

63 characters or less in length.

Consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, -, and ., and must start and end with an alphanumeric character.

The controller will automatically merge ingress rules for all Ingresses in the same Ingress group and support them with a single ALB. Most annotations defined on an Ingress only apply to the paths defined by that Ingress. By default, Ingress resources don't belong to any Ingress group.
```